# Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) error when trying to install unrar from the terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, root

I am getting this error when trying to install *unrar* unarchiver for .rar files from the terminal in Ubuntu.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: please anyone help by solving my error.

Comment: As the error asks, are you root or running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install whatever` should do the trick. Missing **sudo** as pointed out by @JuliePelletier

Comment: I am trying to install  $ sudo apt-get install unrar.but still it showing the same error

Comment: Is this happening on a fresh install?

Comment: rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/* long back i run this command in my terminal.after running this command i am getting  bellow error every time when i am trying to install any software                                                                sudo apt-get install unrar 
[sudo] password for user: 
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Do you get any result when running `sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg`?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/var/lib/dpkg': No such file or directory
this is the result i am getting after entering the sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg

Comment: Then try `sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg` but I suspect the problem could be much worse.

Comment: user@user-Vostro-3800:~$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg
user@user-Vostro-3800:~$ sudo -i
root@user-Vostro-3800:~# sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/dpkg’: File exists

Comment: @hasee, obviously, you're getting the error messages because something is messed up and not working normally.  Your question doesn't contain any history of how you got to this point or diagnostic details.  Some of that is in comments, but it's incomplete and hard to follow.  People will be better able to help if you edit the question and add the detail from the comments (and do it in an organized way).

Comment: @karel, looks like you have some insight that I don't.  You think all of the details in the comments are basically noise (not really relevant to a solution), and the 2nd and 3rd bullets in your answer pretty much have to cover the problem?

Comment: @hasee, I had shut down for the night and now can't tell from the comment timings whether karel's super-cure worked (if it did, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark; that will let people know the problem is solved and identify that as a proven solution for others with a similar problem).  If it didn't solve it, my understanding is that things can get hosed in a way apt can't fix.  I think that's where Julie Pelletier was going with the comment about a fresh install.  Sometimes the most reliable, and fastest, solution is to restore from a backup or do a clean install.  (cont'd)

Comment: See if your system has the Aptik Migration Utility.  That will create a list of all the changes you've made to the stock installation and provide a mechanism to do an automated recreation of the current configuration.

Comment: @hasee:  Please double-check what you tried because `sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg` can not tell you that there is no such file or directory while `sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg` would tell you that it exists.

Comment: Related thread on askUbuntu exchange - [Permission denied, are you root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/223484/605028)

Answer (score 7):

Run the following command  :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Create missing folders (use the command `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/` first to display the existing folders, if somes floders exist do not re-create it agin):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates,methods,available,diversions}
```

Move `dpkg.status.0` and repair the base file:

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get download dpkg
sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb
sudo apt-get download base-files
sudo dpkg -i base-files*.deb
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Check and repair broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

- The error message is asking if you are root in order to be permitted to run a command to install software from the terminal. Use `sudo` before a command to run the command with root privileges, like this:

  ```
  sudo apt install example-package
  ```

  This example command installs a package named *example-package*.
- If you still get a lock error, close the Ubuntu Software Center (Ubuntu 14.04) or Software application (Ubuntu 16.04) and the terminal to unlock `/var/lib/dpkg/`, reopen the terminal and try the command again.
- If you still get a lock error, run this command to show details about the locking process.

  ```
  ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
  ```

  Then open the System Monitor application and kill the process that has the same process ID as the results of the previous command.

---

For the error mentioned in the comment:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Try fixing it by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then try running the command that resulted in the error message again.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install unrar 
[sudo] password for user: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
this is the error now i am getting

Comment: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
I tried above command i got the error as shown bellow                                                                                                   Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgtk-3-bin_3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below to [generate a list of all processes](https://www.tecmint.com/find-linux-processes-memory-ram-cpu-usage/) whose name comprises of the word apt, you will get a list inclusive of all apt or apt-get processes by using ps and [grep commands](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-grep-commands-character-classes-bracket-expressions/) together with a pipeline.

```
ps -A | grep apt
```

For each apt-get or apt process that you can see in the output of the command above, [kill each process](https://www.tecmint.com/find-and-kill-running-processes-pid-in-linux/) using the command below.

The process ID (PID) is found in the first column from the screenshot above.

```
sudo kill -9 processnumber
or
sudo kill -SIGKILL processnumber
```

For instance, in the command below where 9 is the signal number for the SIGKILL signal, will kill the first apt process:

```
sudo kill -9 13431
or
sudo kill -SIGKILL 13431
```

First execute the command below to remove the lock file in the `/var/lib/dpkg/` directory:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Afterwards force package(s) to reconfigure like so:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Alternatively, delete the lock files in the `/var/lib/apt/lists/` and cache directory as below:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Next, update your packages sources list as follows:

```
sudo apt update
or
sudo apt-get update
```

Full info https://www.tecmint.com/fix-unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-lock/