# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: read error in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions': Is a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

While upgrading using `sudo apt-get upgrade` or any installation, an error appears as :

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 read error in '/var/lib/dpkg/diversions': Is a directory
```

I made a new folder for dpkg as the previous one had some lock error.
After making the new dpkg folder, I copied its status file from a backup.
I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1109774/911683) to create the new dpkg folder.

But error in diversions appear after following all this.